# Can anyone please explain difference between ptr+1 and ptr[0]+1

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Assuming `sizeof` integer as 4 bytes and sizeof(int *) as 8 bytes , I'm not getting why  ptr +1  moves forward by the size of 8 bytes and ptr[0]+1 moves forward by the size of 4 bytes.

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int *ptr[3]; //array of 3 elements pointed to integer 
    int *b;

    ptr[0] = a;

    printf("a: %lu\n", a);
    printf("a + 1: %lu\n\n", a+1);

    printf("ptr: %lu\n", ptr);
    printf("ptr + 1: %lu\n", ptr+1);

    printf("ptr[0]: %lu\n", ptr[0]);//ptr[0] holds base address of array a
    printf("ptr[1]: %lu\n\n", ptr[0] + 1 );

    printf("&ptr: %lu\n", &ptr);
    printf("&ptr + 1: %lu\n", &ptr+1);
}
```

Comment: ptr is an array of pointers, not an array of integers.  In a 64-bit environment, pointers are 8 bytes long

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. Please use `"%p"`, not `"%lu"`, to print pointers, and cast your arguments to `(void*)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have an array of pointers to `int` (`int *`).  You expect the address of the second element to be four bytes higher than the address of the first element, and you are asking why this is not so?

If that is indeed your question, the answer is that the size of a pointer is not necessarily the same as the size of an `int`.

On a 64-bit compiler, the size of a pointer would usually be 8 bytes, while the size of an int is likely to be 4 bytes.

You can print out `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(int *)` to see this clearly.

Comment: yah, you're right, I was tired.  I'll fix it now.  Thanks

Comment: Size of int 4 bytes and size of pointer is 8 bytes, but difference between ptr[0]+1 and ptr[0] is 4 byte, why it is so

Comment: I'm confused by your comment.  You seem to have edited it as I was answering.  You asked about why difference between a[0] and a[0] + 1 is 4 bytes (because a is an array of integers).  Now you ask about ptr[0] and ptr[0] + 1 being a difference of 4 bytes; the title of your question asks why it is 8 bytes.  Please clarify.

Comment: So p[0] is nothing but array of integer (as base address of a is copied to p[0], But p is array of pointer to integer, incrementing p will add size of ( int *) where incrementing p[0] = p[0]+sizeof(int) right?? please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I get your question now.  Yes, that is correct.  ptr is an array of int pointers.  ptr[0] is a pointer to an int.  Incrementing a pointer to an int moves forward by the size of an int  Incrementing a pointer to an int * moves forward by the size of an int *

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow little bit confused please check my comments and correct me if I'm wrong, my only question was to know the difference between ptr, ptr+1 and ptr[0],ptr[0]+1. I hope u understood

Comment: Yes.  ptr to ptr+1 is advancing by the size of a pointer to int (8 bytes).  ptr[0] to ptr[0] + 1 is like a to a+ 1, advancing by the size of an int (4 bytes).  I think you got it right in your comment a few minutes ago.

Comment: You're welcome.  If the answer solved your problem/answered your question, you can record that for posterity by marking it as the answer with the check on the upper left of the question, under the place to vote.

Comment: So the normal array like int a[]; is treated as pointer but a+1 will be base address plus sizeof(int), where as pointer like inr *b; b+1 will be address of b + sizeof(int *)  and same goes to array of pointer right

Comment: @SiddharthSidhu-- No. Given `int a[]`, the identifier `a` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array (in most expressions), so `a` is a pointer to `int`, and with `int *b = a + 1`, the difference `b - a` is 4 if `sizeof (int)` is 4. With `int *b = a; b = b + 1;` the exact same arithmetic holds. But with `int *c[]` you have an _array_ of pointers to `int`, and `c` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, which is a pointer to `int`; thus `c` is a pointer to pointer to `int`. So now with `int **d = c + 1` the difference `d - c` would be 8 if `sizeof (int *)` is 8.